# Is there a way to get the actual timestamp when using firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question is about the javascript client.

I have code that goes something like this:

```
const localEvents = [];
const fbEvents = firebase.database().ref("myevents");

fbEvents.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  const e = snapshot.val();
  localEvents.push(e);
});

function createEvent(e) {
  e.time = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  fbEvents.push(e);
}
```

After calling `createEvent({})`, it appears that entries in my `localEvents` list have `time` values which are not equal to the actual entries in the database (the client guesses the timestamp and calls the `child_added` handler before it's actually done a roundtrip to the server).  Is there any way to avoid this, and/or is there any way to get a callback when the *actual* value of the `time` is known?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, using only the snapshot in the listener, to determine if the timestamp comes from the server or is guessed locally.

What you can do instead is use the promise returned from `fbEvents.push(e)` to determine when the write actually succeeds.  A resolved promise which means it was definitely written to Firebase.  The listener callback you get after that will contain the server's updated value.

(Note that with Firestore it is possible to determine if a document was fully written to the server or not.  Just not with Realtime Database.)

Comment: Thanks!
So I should add my own uuid to each event, then add a `then` to `fbEvents.push` that goes through `localEvents` and finds the event in question based on the uuid (well i'll use a hashmap but the idea is the same), and updates the time?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need a UUID.  You could just store the fact that this particular location/reference was updated in the `then` of the push() promise, and check that value in your listener when it's triggered to know if the timestamp is actually updated.

Comment: I don't think the listener gets triggered after the timestamp is actually updated - am I missing something?

Comment: Oh you're using "child_added", which only triggers on a new child.  If you use "child_changed" or "value" you will see the update.